# Does the child View event callback takes precedence?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ecmascript-6

I have a few related backbone Views:

First:

```
App.Views.TreeGrowthBase = App.Views.TreeGrowthBase.extend({
  events: {
    'submit form': 'submitForm',
...
```

and then in the same file:

```
submitForm: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

and elsewhere in the app:

```
App.Views.WineTreeGrowthBase = App.Views.TreeGrowthBase.extend({
  submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

My questions: In that last piece of code... what is the syntax:

```
submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

Is that a method call? Defining a method? Where are the colons?

Which one takes precedence? I imagine the child view's `submitForm` method definition takes place... if it is a method definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Method definition shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

```
submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

This is the method definition shorthand new in ES6 (ECMAScript 2015).

It's equivalent to

```
submitForm: function submitForm(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```

> The shorthand syntax uses named function instead of anonymous
>   functions (as in `foo: function() {}`). Named functions can be called
>   from the function body (this is impossible for anonymous function as
>   there is no identifier to refer to). For more details, see [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Examples).

and works in browser which have the new features available (like other than IE).

## Overriding functions

Any method overridden in a child of a Backbone class (the result of the `extend` function) takes precedence on the parent function. If you would like to call the parent function, it's still possible:

```
submitForm: function(event) {
    // Using the Backbone '__super__'
    ThisClass.__super__.submitForm.apply(this, arguments);
    // Or the JavaScript preferred way
    ParentClass.prototype.submitForm.apply(this, arguments);
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

This is not specific to Backbone. It's the normal behavior of the prototype chain. Backbone just wraps the complexity in a simple [`extend` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1978-L2007).

See this [in-depth answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1218980) for more info.

---

*Do not use `this.constructor.__super__` because it's not guarantied to be the actual class and it could be the constructor of the child class, causing **a call stack overflow**. Favor `MyCurrentClass.__super__`, it's explicit and close the door to potential extending problems.*

Comment: It has to be `this.constructor.__super__` and it can't be `this.__super__`?

Comment: @Jwan622 It's because `this.constructor === ChildClass` and `this.constructor.__super__ === ChildClass.__super__` and `ChildClass.__super__ === ParentClass.prototype`.  I like `this.construtor.__super__` because it removes the hard-coded name of the parent from the function and could potentially avoid hard to track bugs when changing the parent from which the child extends.

Comment: It's clearer to see when looking at the source of Backbone's [`.extend` function](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1978-L2007).

Comment: @Jwan622 I updated my answer to inform you and readers about the potential problems of `this.constructor.__super__`.